# Can someone please tell me why this code wont run?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, math

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++)
arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

console.log(arr)


 for(var i = 0; i <= howM; i++)
 var sum = 0;
 var eXt = arr[i]
 eXt = eXt.replace (/-/g, "");
 for (i = 0; i < eXt.length; i++) {
 sum += parseInt(eXt.substr(i, 1)); }
 console.log(sum);
```

It tells me this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at eval:13:11" which makes no sense to me because its right above it.

Comment: `howM` needs to be a number to be compared to `i` in the loop.

Comment: it is a number, when it prompts for it I put in 4, and it works in the first for loop, I don't see why that would cause an issue with the replace part half way through the function.

Comment: I don't know a lot about the rules of javascript. I know semicolons can be omitted in some cases... are we sure that the `var eXt` line is one of those cases? (I'd add a semicolon at the end of that line.)  But more curious is the space between the function name `replace` and the opening paren. The error makes it seem like javascript is seeing `replace` as a property, and not a function. I suspect the problem is the whitespace before that opening paren. I suggest you try it after  removing that whitespace e.g. `eXt.replace(...)`;

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z8g3n6wk/) try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intetended body of the loop `for(var i = 0; i <= howM; i++)` is not enclosed in braces `{..}`. As a result, only the statement `var sum = 0;` will be executed in the loop. Also, you probably meant to say `i < howM`. So you want something like this for the loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    var eXt = arr[i]
    eXt = eXt.replace (/-/g, "");
    for (i = 0; i < eXt.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(eXt.substr(i, 1));
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: thank you this is the first decent answer ive gotten on this site. if you dont mind me adding on, after the loop runs once it gives me undefined. do you know why it wont run for the other pieces of the array?

Comment: Can you give me the first 2 cards that you entered?

Comment: I've edited my answer above, it may have the solution you are looking for, with explanations for most lines.

Comment: both cards were the same, for testing purposes ive just been useing the same card over and over

Comment: What is that card? Please give me the exact string.

Comment: 4568-4568 is what i used

Comment: And what did you expect `sum` to be equal to at the end of the process?

Answer (score 0):

Check the comments:

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < parseInt(howM); i++)
arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:")); //No curly braces is fine when its a single line. When there's no braces, JS just runs the next line x amount of times

console.log(arr)

var sum = 0; //Create sum out here. Setting it to zero every loop defeats the purpose
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)//You said "i <= howM". Better to use the length of the array that is being looped through
{ //Use curly braces to show what code to execute repeatedly
    var eXt = arr[i]; //Set eXt to the current number
    eXt = eXt.replace("-", ""); //No need for regex
    sum += parseInt(eXt); //Convert the input to a number, then add it to sum
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: ill try using this and see if it works for what im using it for

Comment: still says undefined

Comment: still says undefined

Comment: What is undefined? What browser are you using? Where are you putting this code?

Answer (score 0):

The second `for` loop doesn't have brackets around it. You can ***MUST*** use brackets ***UNLESS*** it is a one line loop. For example:

This is fine:

```
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
    console.log(i);
```

This is NOT:

```
for (var i=0;i<100;i++)
    var x = i;
    x++;
    console.log(x);
```

So the second for loop should be this:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= howM; i++) {
   var sum = 0;
   var eXt = arr[i]
   eXt = eXt.replace (/-/g, "");
   for (i = 0; i < eXt.length; i++) {
       sum += parseInt(eXt.substr(i, 1)); 
   }
   console.log(sum);
}
```

Also in the first `for` loop I would use `arr[i] = value` instead.

Comment: this wont run at all "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Comment: I missed a bracket at the end of the outside for loop, but really you just need to get a book and read it.